# Id creado en un insert

Tags: android

Quiero saber como se puede saber el Id (automatico) creado cuando se inserta un dato en una tabla de la base de datos.
Tengo estas sentencias de insert que funciona bien:

```
  FSDbHelper dbheldivdir = new FSDbHelper(getActivity());
  SQLiteDatabase insertedivdir = dbheldivdir.getWritableDatabase();
  ContentValues contentValuesdivdir = new ContentValues();
  contentValuesdivdir.put(InContract.DivisionesColumnas.DIVISION, NombreDivision + " A");
  contentValuesdivdir.put(InContract.DivisionesColumnas.DIVIDIDO, "S");
  insertedivdir.insert(InContract.DivisionesColumnas.TABLA_DIVISION, null, contentValuesdivdir);
```

y la Base de datos es :

```
    String T_DIVISIONES = "CREATE TABLE " + InContract.DivisionesColumnas.TABLA_DIVISION + " (" +
            InContract.DivisionesColumnas._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "  +
            InContract.DivisionesColumnas.DIVISION + " TEXT NOT NULL, "  +
            InContract.DivisionesColumnas.DIVIDIDO  + " TEXT" + ")";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(T_DIVISIONES);
```

Como puedo saber despues de hacer el insert que ID ha creado.

Gracias.

Comment: El [método `insert` de SQLite](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) retorna el `ID` de la fila que acaba de ser insertada, entonces basta con que recuperes ese valor.

Comment: Ok. Pero como lo hago sin tener que volver a leer o abrir ese fichero.

Comment: @FernandoDelgadoFernandez el método obtiene el id del registro insertado , puedes verlo en la documentación : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues) saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Al llamar el método [insert()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)), puedes obtener el id de la fila insertada si el valor es mayor a -1, en otro caso no hubo inserción a la tabla.

```
long filaInsertada  = insertedivdir.insert(InContract.DivisionesColumnas.TABLA_DIVISION, null, contentValuesdivdir);
if (filaInsertada > -1) {
    //Se inserto correctamente.
    System.out.println("id creado : " + filaInsertada );
}else{
   //Error al insertar.
   System.out.println("!Error al insertar información!");
}
```

Comment: Jorge el método devuelve un dato del tipo `long`, revisa la doc.

Comment: @A.Cedano hola si!, también puede declararse como int ya que el campo esta declarado como "INTEGER PRIMARY " , pero en realidad lo correcto debe ser como dices, declararlo como long.